# How to save session_id as cookie value and send it to server in Android?

Tags: android, json, web-services, cookies, session-cookies

I am working on a app using web services calls.

I am calling my Login webservice as follows

```
String url = "http://mydomaim.com/login.php";

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(userEmail, password, url);
```

It works fine and send me response as show below

```
{
 "userName":"a",
   "login_success":1,
   "user_id":"3",
   "session_id":"1067749aae85b0e6c5c5e697b61cd89d",
   "email":"a"
}
```

I parse this response, and successfully and got the session id in a variable.
Now I have to call an other webservice appending this session_id as cookie value.

**QUESTION**

How to store the `session_id` as the my cookie value in my Android device and call other web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, When login Call this request.

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println("Cookie: " + cookie.toString());

            if (cookie.getName().contains("PHPSESSID"))
                guid = cookie.getValue();

        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
public static void myMethod(Map<String, String> cookies) throws IOException, PortalException {

        HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 60000);

        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 240000);

        try {

            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(connectionManager, httpParams);

            if (cookies != null) {

                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cookies.entrySet()) {

                    BasicClientCookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

                    cookie.setPath("/");
                    cookie.setDomain(new URL(url).getHost());

                    httpClient.getCookieStore().addCookie(cookie);
                }
            }

            HttpRequestBase request = null;

            if (post) {

                request = post(url, params, headers);

            } else {

                request = get(url, params, headers);

            }

            BasicHttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();

            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request, context);

                    //... etc
```

It works for me.

Comment: I have one object Login that has my cookie stored, but I think it's not you are looking for... Let me see, it makes sense to store this cookie if your session expires? I don't think so... What about to create a DefaultHttpClient set your cookie and uses it for all your requests? This way you can persists in memory until your application has finished

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948068/sending-cookie-value-via-httpget-but-not-getting-the-desired-response?noredirect=1#comment24473404_16948068

Comment: Have a look on this link my new question please