# Sending cookie value via httpget but not getting the desired response

Tags: android, json, http, session, session-cookies

I am calling my Login webservice as follows

```
String url = "http://mydomaim.com/login.php";

        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
        JSONObject json = userFunction.loginUser(userEmail, password, url);
```

it works fine and send me response as show below

```
{
 "userName":"a",
   "login_success":1,
   "user_id":"3",
   "session_id":"1067749aae85b0e6c5c5e697b61cd89d",
   "email":"a"
}
```

I parse this response, and successfully and got the session id, and stored it in an static variable(in MainActivity.java) now I have to send this session id as cookie value to my other webservice.

I have done like this

```
public JSONObject getJSONQuestion(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;

        CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
        Cookie cookie = new BasicClientCookie("PHPSESSID",
                MainActivity.SESSION_ID);

                    // MainActivity.SESSION_ID has my session id

        cookieStore.addCookie(cookie);

        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);

        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet,
                localContext);

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
        Log.e("JSON", json);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;
}
```

but I'm not getting the desired response. Please have a look on my cookie code. Where I have made a mistake?

*EDIT*

I get this,

```
{"logout_success":1,"logout_reason":"no_activity_since_15_min"}
```

but I must get this,

```
{


"random_questions":[
      {
         "questionid":"31",
         "question":"I hate V-",
         "answer1":"some answer 1",
         "answer2":"another answer 2",
         "answer3":"yet another answer 3",
         "answer4":"a great answer 4",
         "correct":"3"
      },
      … (more follow) …
   ]

  }
```

*EDIT 2*

here is my php code of session and cookie

```
<?php

$min = 15 * 60;
//$min = 60;

if (time() - $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] > $min) {
    session_destroy();
    setcookie("PHPSESSID", "", time() - 3600, "/"); // delete session cookie  
    echo json_encode(array('logout_success' => 1, 'logout_reason' => 'no_activity_since_15_min'));
    die;
} else {
    $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] = time();
    mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE logged_in_users SET last_activity = " . $_SESSION['LAST_ACTIVITY'] . " WHERE session_id = '" . session_id() . "' ");
}
```

Comment: What is the response or error that you are getting? Can you edit your question and include that as well?

Comment: @QuentinSwain yes just a minut

Comment: @QuentinSwain have a look on my edit. I dont get any error.

Comment: If you are transmitting the correct session value to the server and you are getting a response. It looks like the server is getting confused. I'm guessing your sessions are configured to timeout at 15 minutes based on the message you get in the response. Could it be that the server is timing out your session to early?

Comment: thanks for reply. but I m sure that i m logged in and call this webservice with in 15 mints.

Comment: I can't see what the code in the webservice looks like. Just going off of the information that I can see from the post. If you aren't getting HTTP error responses and are getting some form of valid response from the server it looks like there might be a logic or configuration issue.Hopefully you can find a solution.

Comment: please see my edit 2. my php code. @QuentinSwain

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31282/discussion-between-qadir-hussain-and-quentin-swain)

Comment: Your Java Code seems ok. I think your problem is in your php server. Have you debugged it? If everything it's ok, try to use wireshark to see if your response and request is exactly how you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use that: From [How to save session_id as cookie value and send it to server in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945044/how-to-save-session-id-as-cookie-value-and-send-it-to-server-in-android/18744761#18744761)

```
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
        url += "?" + paramString;
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

        List<Cookie> cookies = httpClient.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
            System.out.println("Cookie: " + cookie.toString());

            if (cookie.getName().contains("PHPSESSID"))
                guid = cookie.getValue();

        }

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. your are my life saver D: