# android login app on website, cookies store

Tags: java, android, cookies

i'm newbie android developer.

im tryning to sign in my appp on website with HttpPost

when i sending login post data it works.

when ai want to send other form with login response header.

i do not know how to save cookies in android to be loggin in.

or save headers after first request and include in second request.

Comment: use sharedpreferences

Comment: You can try with sharedpreferences, check more about it here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Comment: check that Answer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16945044/how-to-save-session-id-as-cookie-value-and-send-it-to-server-in-android/18744761#18744761